# UINavigationController title not aligned with UIBarButton

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a title for my UINavigationBar, set by calling `self.title = "self.title"` in my custom `UINavigationController` and `BarButtonItem` is installed in the storyboard. Does anyone know what the cause of this misalignment might be and how I would go about fixing it? The title font size is set by calling:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 35),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

[image: self.title is not lined up with UIBarButtonItem on the right]

Comment: where is misalignment?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh well the alignment I'd like is the centerY of title and barbutton matching but at the moment the bottom of both are aligned with each other. How do I change that to have centerY alignment?

Comment: Are you using an image for bar button ? if you are using then change the size of image and put again there it will be aligned

Answer (score 0):

Check this method of **UINavigationBar**

```
func setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(_ adjustment: CGFloat, 
                                for barMetrics: UIBarMetrics)
```

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624959-settitleverticalpositionadjustme?language=objc)